# Background Colour for DIV class

Tags: html, css

I have a DIV class filled with different elements as of now. Now, I want to give that entire `div` class (not the `container`, just the `login` `div`) a background-colour, which just surrounds that `div` with a little bit of space on the top, bottom, left and right (around `10px`). However, when I try giving the `div` a background colour, it does this:

[image]

The background colour for the elements is all over the place. I don't want to move the elements in any different position. I just want the background colour to surround the elements perfectly, with just a little space on the top, bottom, left and right (of `10px`). How can I accomplish this?

This is all my code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lora&display=swap');
body {
  background-color: #DBE2EF;
  position: fixed;
}

.textHead {
  font-family: Lora;
  margin-left: 340px;
  margin-top: 130px;
}

.logintxt {
  font-family: Lora;
  margin-left: 285px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.loginemailtxt {
  font-family: Lora;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 250px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 285px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.loginemailtxt::placeholder {
  color: black;
  padding-left: 3px;
}

.loginpwdtxt {
  font-family: Lora;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 250px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: -256px;
  margin-top: 130px;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: fixed;
}

.loginpwdtxt::placeholder {
  color: black;
  padding-left: 3px;
}

.loginbtn {
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 220px;
  margin-left: -190px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #3F72AF;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Lora;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="login">
    <h2 class="textHead">MedConnect</h2>
    <h2 class="logintxt">Log In to Your Account</h2>
    <input type="text" class="loginemailtxt" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
    <input type="password" class="loginpwdtxt" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <button class="loginbtn" type="button" name="button">Log In</button>
    <h5 style="margin-top: 230px; margin-left: 310px; font-family: Lora;">Don't have an Account? <u style="cursor: pointer;">Sign Up</u></h5>
    <h6 style="margin-top: 40px; margin-left: 260px; font-family: Lora;">By clicking "Log In", you agree to our <u style="cursor: pointer;">Terms</u> and <u style="cursor: pointer;">Privacy Policy</u></h6>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove all sorts of `position: fixed` declarations as they tend to mess with layouts (in general, they're hard to work with)

Also adjusted some widths and margins that are not needed.  Mainly, you need somethign like this:

```
.login{
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 10px;
   background-color: green;
   width: 300px;
   text-align: center;
}
```

See sample code below (which should get you closer to what you want)

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lora&display=swap');
body {
  background-color: #DBE2EF;
  font-family: Lora;
}

.login{
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 10px;
   background-color: green;
   width: 300px;
   text-align: center;
}

input, button{
  margin: 10px;
}

.loginemailtxt {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 250px;
  height: 30px;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.loginemailtxt::placeholder {
  color: black;
  padding-left: 3px;
}

.loginpwdtxt {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 250px;
  height: 30px;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.loginpwdtxt::placeholder {
  color: black;
  padding-left: 3px;
}

.loginbtn {
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #3F72AF;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="login">
    <h2 class="textHead">MedConnect</h2>
    <h2 class="logintxt">Log In to Your Account</h2>
    <input type="text" class="loginemailtxt" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
    <br/>
    <input type="password" class="loginpwdtxt" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <br/>
    <button class="loginbtn" type="button" name="button">Log In</button>
    <h5>Don't have an Account? <u style="cursor: pointer;">Sign Up</u></h5>
    <h6>By clicking "Log In", you agree to our <u style="cursor: pointer;">Terms</u> and <u style="cursor: pointer;">Privacy Policy</u></h6>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *I don't want to move the elements in any different position.*. Well first step, remove your layout and center it! :')

Comment: Hey @blurfus. This is completely changing the look and making everything look weird. It's also moving the elements to a different position. I think the width factor as well is making the elements and text look jumbled and out of place. I tried changing it, but that doesn't work as well.

Comment: Hey, after a little bit of adjusting, I got it. Thanks!